# TFLite: Unable to obtain Inference using MobilenetV2 on custom Dataset

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have followed [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#Tuning) link and successfully created frozen graph for MoiblenetV2_1.4_224 by fine tuning on my custom dataset. 
Then, I followed the [tensorflow-for-poets:tflite](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/index.html#0) to create the tflite graph using toco using following command.

```
IMAGE_SIZE=224
toco \
--input_file=frozen_mobilenet_v2.pb \
--output_file=optimized_graph.lite \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--input_shape=10,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3 \
--input_array=input \
--output_array=MobilenetV2/Predictions/Softmax \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_data_type=FLOAT
```

The lite graph was successfully created but during inference, while running the tflite Interpretor I get the following error. Due to this, I am not getting any inferences.

```
Input error: Failed to get input dimensions. 0-th input should have 6021120 bytes, but found 602112 bytes.
```

Comment: Can you try to visualize the graph in Tensorboard. or try to convert to pbtxt file and ensure input node is correctly named?
import tensorflow as tf
path_to_pb = '...'
output_file = '...'
g = tf.GraphDef()
with open(path_to_pb, 'r') as f:
  g.ParseFromString(str(f.read()))
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
  f.write(str(g))

Comment: I found the issue. Answer below. Turns out your flags themselves had a typo. In the context, note that the above comment is only meant for debugging past that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this argument --input_array=Predictions. 
You can try to use quantized model

Answer (score 0):

> Input error: Failed to get input dimensions.

The commandline flag should be `--input_arrays` and not `--input_array`. (Plural instead of singular).
Ditto `--output_arrays` instead of `--output_array`. That should resolve your error. So the command should be:

```
IMAGE_SIZE=224
toco \
--input_file=frozen_mobilenet_v2.pb \
--output_file=optimized_graph.lite \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--input_shape=10,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3 \
--input_arrays=input \
--output_arrays=MobilenetV2/Predictions/Softmax \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_data_type=FLOAT
```

#### Additional debugging tip

For future reference, if your flags are all correct, then next step would be to check that your input and output tensor names are correct. You can try to visualize the inputs and outputs of your graph in Tensorboard or convert to pbtxt as follows and then read it out:

```
import tensorflow as tf
path_to_pb = '...'
output_file = '...'
g = tf.GraphDef()
with open(path_to_pb, 'rb') as f:
  g.ParseFromString(f.read())
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
  f.write(str(g))
```

Comment: I ran the code you gave. It gives me following error. g.ParseFromString(tmp)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message

Comment: I updated the open to use 'rb'. Can you give it a try? In any case, did using --input_arrays work?

Comment: Also note that this is just an additional debugging tip. In your case, turns out that the flags had a typo. I clarified that in the answer.

Comment: I have the graph.pbtxt file but it contains all nodes of the graph. How do I identify the input and output ones?

Comment: You already have the input and output nodes: 'input'
and 'MobilenetV2/Predictions/Softmax' respectively. So you need to say in your commandline --input_arrays=input \
--output_arrays=MobilenetV2/Predictions/Softmax \